# What is a "final" excise tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, sales-tax

Looking at the article [here](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tips/small-business-taxes/what-is-irs-form-720/L7PrBcYjz) on quarterly excise tax returns form 720 it says

> You must always file when you collect any excise tax during the current quarter or if you were responsible for collecting excises taxes during any quarter during the year **and you have not filed a final excise tax return**.

The only reference I could find to a "final" excise tax return was [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/notices/cp178_english.pdf) where it says

> If you no longer owe excise tax, file a final Form next quarter.

What is confusing about this to me is that the previous snippet makes it seem like the you would file a final return if had collected excise taxes, yet this snippet implies you would only file a final return if NO excise taxes were collected.

Could anyone with more experience explain this to me? What exactly is a "final" excise tax return and basically when do you file form 720s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i720#idm139958484331024 :

> **Final Return.**
>
> File a final return if you have been filing Form 720 and you:
>
> 1. Go out of business, or
> 2. Won't owe excise taxes that are reportable on Form 720 in future quarters.

In other words if you have collected tax this quarter, but *won't* do so in the future, you file a final return with the collected tax. If you have *not* collected tax this quarter and won't in the future, you file the return with *no* tax and checked to indicate there won't be any in the future either. If you have not collected tax this quarter but are still in business and expect to collect in the future, you must file the return with no tax, to indicate there was no tax, but will or may be in the future.

This same technique is used with other more common IRS forms to indicate when there aren't expected to be any more filings of the same type by the same taxpayer. If you miss or skip filing a periodic return and *didn't* previously indicate 'final', the IRS systems will often send you an automatic reminder. Filing the 'final' return tells them *not* to expect future filings.

---

> when do you file form 720s

If you mean at what time, https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i720#idm139958484359856 :

> **When To File.**
>
> You must file a return for each quarter of the calendar year as follows.
>
> [table showing last day of month after the quarter, too much trouble to reformat for Stack]
>
> ...
>
> [exception for] **Floor stocks tax.** Report the floor stocks tax on ozone-depleting chemicals (ODCs), IRS No. 20, on the return due by July 31 of each year. ...

If you mean under what circumstances, https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i720#idm139958484367152 :

> **Who Must File.**
>
> See Patient-centered outcomes research fee (IRS No. 133) in *Part II* for special rules about who must file to report the patient-centered outcomes research fee.
>
> You must file Form 720 if:
>
> - You were liable for, or responsible for collecting, any of the federal excise taxes listed on Form 720, Parts I and II, for a prior quarter and you haven’t filed a final return; or
> - You are liable for, or responsible for collecting, any of the federal excise taxes listed on Form 720, Parts I and II, for the current quarter.
>
> ...

Each of the particular taxes listed later has its own specific instructions on Who Must File (and pay).

For the tax on communication services,

> The person receiving the payment for communications services must collect and submit the tax and file the return.

For the tax on air transportation services,

> The person receiving the payment for air transportation services must [collect and submit the tax and file the return, with certain exceptions]

Et cetera, et cetera, Yul Brynner.

(Aside: although I didn't write these, I can freely post them under Stack's terms because works of the US (Federal) government are not copyright under a special exception in the law.)